# Hibernate mapping - "Could not determine type"

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I currently have the following objects persisting successfully:

- **Person** first name, etc.
- **Exams** title, date, etc.

I'd like to now create a third table **Exam results**. For this table I believe it should be person ID, exam ID and result, and this is a many to many relationship.

```
@Entity
public class ExamResult {
    private Exam exam;
    private Person person;
    private double value;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="EXAM_ID")
    public Exam getExam() {
        return exam;
    }
    public void setExam(Exam exam) {
        this.exam = exam;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

The error:

> > org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Person, at table: ExamResult, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(person)]

I think I may be going about this the wrong way, but I can't work out how to proceed with this relationship from the
[tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html).

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know what can be wrong either... Can you please show the `Person` class?

Comment: There is an open issue about this http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4226

Comment: @incarnate, the `Person` class was a POJO without mentioning `ExamResult` in any way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have multiple `@Id` annotations in the same entity. Use a composite ID instead.
[Example.](http://java-aap.blogspot.com/2006/04/hibernate-annotations-composite.html)

Comment: Thanks, that example does look like what I'm trying to achieve. I am going through it.